# Angular 2: How do validate placeholder based on boolean condition

Tags: angular

I have one textbox and initially it would be displaying some placeholder

```
<textarea class="some class" placeholder={{Some placeholder from REST API}}><textarea>
```

I want to disable this placeholder based on some boolean condition?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<textarea [placeholder]="condition ? 'haha' : ''"></textarea>
```

If the placeholder from API is contained in variable, say: "apiPlaceHol"
Then use it like this:

```
<textarea [placeholder]="condition ? apiPlaceHol : ''"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable for placeholder say **placeholdervalue** in the component.

```
<textarea class="some class" [placeholder]="placeholdervalue"><textarea>
```

Set **placeholdervalue** to null based on your conditions in the component.

```
this.placeholdervalue = null;
```

Hope it helps!!